# d3 multi-line chart with different names for features/variables

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gl6N.png) is the current status of my project

I have data that is nested by country and year in the following format:

```
 nestedData = [{"country": "england", 
                "values": [{"year": 1888,
                            "feature1": "someValue",
                            "feature2": "someValue"},
                           {"year": 1989,
                            "feature1": "someValue",
                            "feature2": "someValue"}]
               },
               {"country": "germany", 
                "values": [{"year": 1900,
                            "feature1": "someValue",
                            "feature2": "someValue"},
                           {"year": 1991,
                            "feature1": "someValue",
                            "feature2": "someValue"}]
               }]
```

From a drop-down menu users can select a country. Currently I store the data of the selected country, as well as its index (in `nestedData`) in global variables:

```
var selectedIndex = 0  // default value
var countryData = data[selectedIndex].values
```

For a particular feature (here: feature1) I create a line with:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.year); })
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.feature1); });

d3.select("#viz1")
    .append("path")
    .data([countryData])
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("id", "feature1")
    .attr("d", line);
```

Furthermore my visualization does also include checkboxes that represent features. Clicks on these checkboxes shall trigger additional lines in the same figure.

### The Question

Now my problem is that I don't know how to program that clicking on checkboxes produces additional lines in a generic way. I was trying to pass the name of the feature which is clicked into `d3.svg.line()`, such that I could do something along the lines of:
`.y(function(d) { return yScale(d.featureName); });` but I could not find a way to accomplish this.

Another idea was to re-arrange the data into the following form, every time a checkbox is clicked:

```
rearrangedData = [{"year": 1888, "value": "someValue"},
                  {"year": 1989, "value": "someValue"}, ...]
// value now stands for the selected feature, e.g. feature1
```

Now the snippet `.y(function(d) { return yScale(d.value); });` could work with any feature that should be drawn. But I doubt this to be an efficient way of solving this.

I would greatly appreciate your help and any suggestions on how I can improve my code. Though, please go easy on me, since I started out with D3 two weeks ago.

Comment: this might help https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955

Comment: Pass in the feature as a variable, `passedInFeatureName`, then `.y(function(d) { return yScale(d[passedInFeatureName]; });`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. @Mark How exactly do I pass `passedInFeature` into line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very basic example.  Define your line function as:

```
var line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x(function(d) {
      return x(d.year);
    });
```

Note, there is not `.y` accessor.

Set up a func:

```
function drawLine(whichFeature){

    // set up .y on each call
    line.y(function(d) {
      return y(d[whichFeature]);
    });

    plot.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return line(d.values);
      })
      .style("stroke", function(d){
        return z(d.country);
      })
  }
```

And call it as:

```
drawLine("feature1");
drawLine("feature2");
```

---

Full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 80,
      bottom: 80,
      left: 50
    },
    width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y%m%d");

  var x = d3.scaleOrdinal().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

  var line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x(function(d) {
      return x(d.year);
    });
    
  nestedData = [{
    "country": "england",
    "values": [{
      "year": 1888,
      "feature1": 10,
      "feature2": 20
    }, {
      "year": 1989,
      "feature1": 15,
      "feature2": 35
    }]
  }, {
    "country": "germany",
    "values": [{
      "year": 1900,
      "feature1": 21,
      "feature2": 36
    }, {
      "year": 1991,
      "feature1": 12,
      "feature2": 25
    }]
  }]


  x.domain(d3.map(nestedData, function(d) {
    return d.year;
  }));

  y.domain([
    d3.min(nestedData, function(c) {
      return d3.min(c.values, function(d) {
        return Math.min(d.feature1, d.feature2);
      });
    }),
    d3.max(nestedData, function(c) {
      return d3.max(c.values, function(d) {
        return Math.max(d.feature1, d.feature2);
      });
    })
  ]);

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", "0.71em")
    .attr("fill", "#000");

  var plot = g.selectAll(".plot")
    .data(nestedData)
    .enter().append("g");

  drawLine("feature1");
  drawLine("feature2");
  
  function drawLine(whichFeature){
    
    line.y(function(d) {
      return y(d[whichFeature]);
    });
    
    plot.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return line(d.values);
      })
      .style("stroke", function(d){
        return z(d.country);
      })
  }
    
</script>
```